# What is it called when a group of vocalists or chorus sing Ooh's oh's, ah's, etc?

Tags: voice, choir, lyrics

I heard my chorus director refer to it as something sounding like dest cant or something, but since I'm hard-of-hearing, I couldn't hear all the letters.

If someone can give me the correct name for this, as well as more information and resources about it, that would be excellent.

Comment: 'Descant'? But it's not really oohs and ahs. Descant is singing another part over the top, literally, of an existing melody. Singing oohs and ahs is simply 'songs without words' - although there's probably an authorised word for that.

Comment: @Tim, maybe the teacher meant "distant" singer, not *descant*

Comment: I think I've found now the correct term (s. the edit of my answer: BV'S = **backing vocals**

Comment: There is a word "descant", which is defined in the answers below. The word for "oohs" and "aahs" is "vocalise", which you can read about here: [Is there terminology for vocals that do not use lyrics in certain parts?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/111019/is-there-terminology-for-vocals-that-do-not-use-lyrics-in-certain-parts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term would not be "descant"

The term you and your director are looking for is "vocable"

We use the term "vocable" to describe sounds singers make that are outside of intelligible language. Beyond "oohs" and "aahs" it would also include whoops, screams, pops, clicks, lip buzzes and any of the other thousands of sounds the human voice can make.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vocable

Comment: I'm not sure if I should post this as a separate question, but someone told me that a song I showed them had descant in it, or counterpoint or countermelody. It makes me associate it with a mashup because you have a second melody mixed in with the first. It was Joy to the World in 3/4 time, mixed with The First Noel.

Answer (score 1):

A descant is a melody added above the main melody.  Common in festive arrangements of hymns.  Maybe this was the word he used to describe the oohs and ahs, though it doesn't specifically mean that.

I can't think of a word that exclusively means that sort of singing except 'oohs and ahs'.  Maybe 'vocalising' would cover, if not define it.

Comment: I don't think he said descant ...

Comment: Any other suggestions for 'something sounding like dest cant or something' ?

Comment: (The downvote is not from me.) Now I would agree with you that the leader might have  said descant. But I’m still searching for a term. As we say *humming* for consonants it should be **ooing** or **aaing**

Comment: This is so clearly the right answer. It explains descant, which we should assume the director used intentionally - unlike the accepted answer - and it explains _vocalise_ which is the point of the question in the title. The OP basically asked two questions.

Answer (score 1):

In captioning, it is generally described as "vocalizing" or "harmonizing." Neither of these are exact definitions but they connote what's going on for a deaf viewer who is not a musicologist, especially when used in context. As used in this way, vocalizing and harmonizing are located on a continuum between singing and scatting.

Answer (score 0):

> What is it called when a group of vocalists or chorus sing Ooh's oh's, ah's,

In my Gospel choir and school classes

I used the term "back ground"

back-ground voicing or back-ground singing

The typical arrangement of aah and oohs is that they are just homophone voicing the lead singer harmonizing the chords like an organ or guitar accompaniment.

(Of course will find  also polyphonic background voicing.)

Edit:

I've deleted the links provided as they haven't been corresponding to my text above. What I mean is not the same as backing voices or backup singers or also barbershop style.

I just  taught the children to sing the chords (triads) following the tune in half notes or whole notes e.g. the background voices in Hey Jude.

Maybe the term *"background"* has changed its meaning through the years, but that's what we have used in Swiss Jazz School in the late sixties. And I would still use it in Jazz arrangements where instruments are playing divided chord notes like the Aah and Oh in harmony of human voices.

**Edit:**

I thought that  distinguished to consonants like mm, hm, nn, ng this kind of vocal accompaniment  will be called vowel background.

But now here is the link with the correct answer:

**BV's = BACKING VOCALS**

https://www.soundonsound.com/techniques/crafting-perfect-pop-backing-vocals

Comment: That doesn't exclusively mean oohs and ahs though.

Comment: yes, it can mean also all vocal parts responding or accompanying the lead-singer. But aahs and oohs mean surely background.

The question is related with some questions here like e.g.


https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/48369/what-is-the-anatomy-of-a-song/48386#48386

Comment: The term background singer is also used instead of backing singer.

Comment: good information!
https://www.music-jobs.com/uk/jobtypes/backing-vocalist-jobs-402849.php

Comment: Oohs and Aahs are probably 'background'.  But 'background' doesn't necessarily mean Oohs and Ahs.